# How to set the common background In SVG?

Tags: svg

How to set the common background for all svg?

```
<svg>
 <g id="dsfdf">
  -----------
 </g>
 <g id="dsfgfdgdf">
  -----------
 </g>
</svg>
```

How to set the common background for G tags. Please any one help

Comment: Put a rect element in each <g> tag and colour it the way you want. Or if you want the same colour, put a rect element as the first <svg> child and colour that.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the fill in the svg element itself, you can always specify another color in the containing elements, like the red circle on the first position in the sample.

```
<svg fill="green" id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
  <circle id="circle1" r="30" cx="100" cy="34" style="fill: red; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2"/>
  <circle id="circle2" r="30" cx="200" cy="34"/>
  <circle id="circle3" r="30" cx="300" cy="34"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: any possible set  backgrond in image ?